# Swift - multiple extension with different method name but still not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have two framework projects (A and B) and in both the frameworks I have a UIViewController Extension.

1. My extension in framework B has method "loadFromNib"
2. In framework "B" I have classes accessing "loadFromNib"
3. In framework "B" I also refer the framework "A"
4. Now I have added UIViewController extension to Framework "A" but with the name "loadViewFromNib".

Now my existing classes throw error that loadFromNib is not available and suggests me to access the loadViewFromNib method. What is that I am missing here. Why my classes are not referring to the right extension

```
//Code from Framework B
extension UIViewController
{
    public class func loadFromNib() -> Self?
    {
        return loadNibFilePrivateMethod()
    }
    ....
}

//Code from Framework A
extension UIViewController
{
    public class func loadViewFromNib() -> Self?
    {
        return loadNibFilePrivateMethod()
    }
    ....
}
```

I am in the process of merging common code to Framework A  from multiple other frameworks (owned by other teams) and cannot modify anything in any other frameworks. So I want my code to co-exist without breaking anything.

Comment: `Now my existing classes throw error that loadFromNib is not available`  are the classes in framework B?

Comment: Please show some code. The definition of `loadFromNib` in framework A to start with.

Comment: @JeremyP updated the post with some code.

Comment: @AnilVarghese yes they still exists in Framework B. As I don't have access to modify them. Updated my post above as well

Comment: Have you got `import B` at the top of the source files where you reference `loadFromNib`?

Comment: @JeremyP it is in the same framework project

Comment: But you talk about two frameworks. Even if they are in the same project, if code in framework A needs to use code in framework B, the code in A has to import B.

Answer (score 0):

> Now my existing classes throw error that loadFromNib is not available

Possibly because you are trying to use `loadFromNib` from outside the framework where it is declared? (That's what the error message *...not available* means)

When you want a method/type/function to be available to other modules (think frameworks, targets) you need to declare them as `public`.

So to resolve your issue, declare you method

`public func loadFromNib(...`

and it will be available most likely.

**Update**

Are you calling the methods on a viewcontroller instance or on a view? The name suggests ambiguity in what they are expected to do.

Comment: When I use myView.loadFromNib() from Framework B, I get the error Type myView has no member 'loadFromNib'. This is an existing code in Framework B and was working early. I see this message after I added the new extension to my Framework A

Comment: @Tamil I see `loadFromNib` is an extension of UIVIewController. `myView.loadFromNib()` would not work then. Check whether you calling on View or Controller object